# In android how to move the complete node of accepted requests to history node and remove it from accepted node

Tags: java, android, firebase

In android how to move the complete node of accepted requests to history node and remove it from accepted node like i want to move the accepted request node first child driver id,second nested node child is passenger id and third is the accepted request id and below it the accepted request details

[image: the firebase database image]

Now i want to move the first child driver id,second nested node child is passenger id and third is the accepted request id and below it the accepted request details all these to be under a new node named history and remove it from accepted node as journeyCompletedStatus=completed**

Comment: You can't 'move' nodes in Firebase, nor can you rename keys. It's a simple matter of reading the node you want to 'move', write it to a new location and remove it from the original location.

Comment: how to remove it from original location guide me because don't know exactly how to do it

Comment: See the Firebase Guide [Delete Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#delete_data) section.